# python sasl C1083 error

Tags: python, sasl, pyhive

I am trying to install sasl-0.1.3 for python on windows 10 but am getting a    `C1083` fatal error, it is referencing Visual Studio C++ and states `failed to build wheel for sasl` in the error message.

I was wondering if there are any solutions that do not include wheels as my office has restrictions for those.

Comment: Can you please paste the complete error message/stack trace? Does it mention anything about missing SDKs/headers?

Comment: C1083 → Compiler could not open a file. Most likely there's a lib or its header files missing.